# Sampling Calibration

Tags: sampling, calibration

I was trying to work out by hand the first example in the following PDF link entitled [The calibration software CALMAR – What is it?](http://vesselinov.com/CalmarEngDoc.pdf)

The example is given below for convenience:

> Example 1:
>   We consider a population of size N=120 from which a simple random sample of size
>   n=15 is drawn. We also consider a numerical variable x. The values taken by that
>   variable on the sampled units (we assume no non-response) are: 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6,
>   7, 8, 11, 12, 10, 15, 20 and 50. The weighted sum of x is 150 * 8 = 1200.
>
> Suppose now that the exact population total of that variable is known and equals
>   1400. We would like to use CALMAR to calibrate the sample to this auxiliary total. In
>   other words, we would like to slightly modify the initial weights so the sum of x based
>   on the new weights is 1400.

The answer they gave is

```
8.0546
8.0546
8.0546
8.1091
8.1091
8.2182
8.3273
8.3819
8.4364
8.6001
8.6547
8.5456
8.8183
9.0911
10.7278
```

The formulas to calculate them are in Section 2.1, which took some time to figure out and is calculated as

$w_k = d_k  \left( 1 + \frac{1400-\sum d_k x_k }{\sum d_k x_k^2} x_k \right)$

Where $x=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 10, 15, 20, 50]$ and $d=8$ for all k.

They later state

> CALMAR increased the design weights so the benchmark total of 1400 can be
>   reached. The design weight of the unit o was most increased as the unit carries the
>   highest value for the variable x. Conversely, the design weights of a, b and c
>   remained almost the same as the values taken by x on these units are small.

**Questions:**

1. If they are just linearly scaling from 1200 to 1400, and all initial weights are the same, why isn't the new weights all just equal to $8*(1400/1200)=9.3333$?
2. Confused on their later comment, why should the design weight of the highest value be moved the most? In fact, in this case, why are the weights different at all?
3. The $(1+...)$ term in their formula seems to imply that going from a sample to a population all weights should increase. What if the sample over-sampled a particular group? Given population constraints, shouldn't the new weights be less than the initial in that case?

**EDIT**

Realized a matrix solution to their formula. Assume you want the calibrated weights to satisfy $AW=B$ and you have an initial sampling weight vector $d$. Then their calibrated weights can be calculated as:

$W_{cal} = d + A^+(B-Ad)$

Where $A^+$ is the Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse.

The example above would have

$A=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 10, 15, 20, 50]$

$B=[1400]$

$d=[8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]^T$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlooked part of the rationale for the procedure. The new weights must be *as close as possible to the sampling weights.*  The criterion for closeness in the example is:

$$
Q_1= \sum_{i \epsilon s} \frac{(\omega_k- d_k)^2}{d_k}
$$
where $\omega_k$ is the calibrated weight and $d_k$ is the original weight.

The value for $Q_1$ is 3.333 for the equal weights; 1.364 with the calibrated weights. The calibrated weights will in general be unequal.

2. The equation for weights that you quote:

$$
\omega_k = d_k  \left( 1 + \frac{1400-\sum d_k x_k }{\sum d_k x_k^2} x_k \right)
$$

can be written as:

$$
\frac{\omega_k}{d_k} = 1 + C \thinspace x_k
$$

where $C$ is a constant for the problem. Thus the ratio of calibrated to original weight is a linear function of $x_k$ and  will be larger for the larger $x$'s.

3. The method also works when there is oversampling.  The extreme case is where some observations are selected with certainty, so that $d_k=1$. However, it is possible to have $C<0$.  Starting with small $d_k$ could lead to negative calibrated weights. To guard against against this, one should choose one of the three distance options other than $Q_1$ in CALMAR

A good reference is:

Sarndal, C.E. 2007. The calibration approach in survey theory and practice. Survey Methodology 33, no. 2: 99-119.

http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/12-001-x/2007002/article/10488-eng.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. One addition concern: Although point 2 does answer the reason why the weight of the largest measurement increased the most, on an algebraic level, it still doesn't make sense on an intuitive level why that should be the case (regardless of expression for Q1). If there is only one constraint such as above, the impact of moving the weight for 50 a little bit has 50x more impact of that same movement for observation of 1.  It seems that the weight of 50 should move the least from d=8, not the most. [continued...]

Comment: [...] If you increased the 1400 constraint to, say, 14 million and the calibrated weight of observation 50 would be near 50x more than the calibrated weight of observation 1. Image these as household incomes, the household with the largest value now has 50 more weight than the household with the smallest? Seems more biased than before. Just trying to understand the intuition. Thanks!

Comment: It's always dangerous to draw conclusions about a method from a small data set concocted for instructional purposes. 
\vskip

• The 34% relative increase in the weight for the X = 50 observation is not large compared to increases I've seen in practice after post-stratification raking. If I observed a really large increase, say more than two-fold, I'd use one of the methods that allows bounds on the weights.

Comment: This is obviously a concocted data set,  Even so, the 34% relative increase in the weight for the X = 50 observation is not large compared to increases I've seen in practice after post-stratification raking. If I observed a really large increase, I'd use one of the methods that allows bounds on the weights. But I would not expect a big effect in practice, when calibration will be based on many variables. Because the revised weight is a function of a linear combination of those variables, the effect of any single variable will be diminished.

Comment: A likely by-product of calibration is that the new weights will be more variable than the original. As a result, standard errors will increase. This  will generally be offset by a large reduction in bias, with a corresponding large decrease in mean square error. To criticize a large weight, one must show that this benefit is threatened.

Comment: Unfortunately, the 14 million total you assume to make the argument in your last post is not believable. The upper 99% confidence limit for the total of X (calculated on the sample with the original weights) is 2,347. With the revised weights (pretending the X total isn't known), the limit is 2,846.  Such a  difference ordinarily indicates a poor design (e.g SRS of unequally sized clusters instead of sampling probabilities proportional to size) or normalized weights. For the SRS design, large revised weights from post-stratification/calibration are needed to reduce bias.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I will definitely read more about the procedures, and the reference you provided.